# ? added to outputstream - encoding issue?

Tags: java, encoding, printwriter

I'm currently trying to manipulate maya 2008 files (.md) with Java. Within this files there are some passage in the text that I have to replace."MY15" should be converted into "MY16". After I replaced this substring it is written to a new file.

Because the new file could not be opened in Maya I just copy the given File to a new File.
If I open these two files in a diff-tool I get differences even if I don't replace anything within this files.

For example:

`"DBLE@@ATTRda"` becomes `"DBLE@?@ATTRda"`

But not all `@` elements are replaced by `?@`.

(Other example: `>ãÁ@` -> `>?ãÁ@`)

I'm creating these files with an PrintWriter.

```
in = new FileReader(new File(inputPath));
writer = new PrintWriter(outpath, in.getEncoding());
writer.print(content);
writer.flush();
writer.close();
```

What is the bug within this code?

Comment: Is the file format text data and not binary data?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean '.mb' (instead of '.md'). This is a binary file format that contains binary data, not text data. So reading it with a `FileReader` will not work as it will convert all the bytes of the file to text which doesn't make sense!

Instead you should use an `FileInputStream` and work with bytes instead of chars.

Comment: I have thought about it but haven't find a way to replace the given String "MY15" by the new String "MY16" within the FileInputStream.
Is there a possibility?

Comment: As far as i have found out now there is no possible way to manipulate an FileInputStream.
The wierd thing about is that if you open these files in notepad you can manipulate it without any problems. So why should this not be possible in java?

Comment: An InputStream by definition is just a stream of byte data. It's solely for reading data from some source (e.g. a file). In that way its identical to a Reader, only that the latter is for reading character data. Using a Reader or InputStream you are not able to modify a file in place, you can only create a modified copy. Try to use a RandomAccessFile instead.